# Why are these clouds rendering wrong? (updated so you can see the images)

Tags: rendering, lighting

Basically to make these clouds I used an ocean modifier. This is my first project in blender (never animated before this) and I'm trying to make a psx type look so I'm using eevee for rendering. I tried turning on and off the different lights in my scene and it doesn't effect this massive black square on it. It seems like that section may be rendering incorrectly.

Here's what it looks like in the viewport:
[image]

Here's what it looks like rendered out:
[image]

Here's what it looks like rendered with a area light underneath it:
[image]

As you can see it looks correct outside of that black area... been trying to troubleshoot this for a while. Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: Could you up upload your .blend file? Problems regarding differences between viewport and final render are usually easy to fix. https://blend-exchange.com/